# how to connect mongodb-datasource to jasper

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

I have a jrxml file which has database as MongoDB and I have generated the JRXML file desgined through Ireport 5.6.0 , I need to compile jrxml file and generate as PDF how to do it through JAVA code. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/mongodb

Comment: @WojtekO.- I need the Java code to run the jrxml file which has datasource as MongoDB